# Is it possible to apply the same styles to both min-width and min-device-width?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm in a situation where I can't technically add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Is it possible to create a rule such as:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) or (min-width:768){
```

Or should have the same CSS twice (the first in min-device-width and the second in a seperate min-width rule.

Or should I just use min-device-width and accept if someone has resized their browser, the CSS won't apply.

Comment: Yes, you can add a single css for multiple rule.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `or` operator for Media Queries, what you can do is a comma-separated list:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px), only screen and (min-width:768)
```

If any of the media queries in the list evaluates to true, your style will be applied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The only problem with this I foresee is that if a desktop user resizers their browser to a smaller size - the styles would still be applied due to the 'min-device-width'). Whereas, if I was able to do the viewport thing, i could just set min-width and not bother with the device width.

Comment: can't you use the `not` operator? what really is the condition you're trying to build?

Comment: I want it to be based on width, but also apply to devices with higher resolutions.

Comment: why do you need the device-width? Note that it's already deprecated in Media Queries 4

Comment: As i have no viewport meta tag. This describes the effect: "Starting with Safari on iOS (or whatever we were supposed to be calling iOS back then), mobile browser viewports have been "virtual". Although the viewport may only take up (for example) 320 physical pixels-worth of space in the interface, the browser creates a "virtual" viewport that's larger (980 pixels wide by default on iOS, I think) and renders content in there, then zooms that virtual viewport out until it fits into the actual physical pixels available on the device’s screen.".